# CSS animation only working in google chrome?

Tags: css, animation, browser

This is the code, currently it works with google chrome, but not with safari? I need it to work with most browsers, hopefully some of you can help me, thx!

```
#changing::before{
    content: "depression?";
    animation: animate infinite 20s;
    padding-left: 10px;
    animation-delay: 2s;
}

@keyframes animate {

    0% {
        content: "stress?";
    }

    50% {
        content: "angst?";
    }

    100% {
        content: "depression?";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Animating content is always buggy with Safari, try something different:

```css
#changing::before {
  content: "depression? \Astress? \A angst?";
  white-space: pre;
  display: inline-block;
  animation: animate infinite 2s steps(3); /* change the number if you will have more text */
  padding-left: 10px;
}
#changing {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  height:1.2em; /* same as line-height*/
  overflow:hidden;
}

@keyframes animate {
  to{transform:translateY(-100%);}
}
```

```html
<div id="changing"></div>
```

Comment: I see that this animation works with safari (nice!), however it changes the y position of the three lines? instead of changing the displayed saved as "content"?

Comment: @Sjelstrup yes, I am using translation to show one line among the 3 and no more rely on changing the content (which is buggy)